# Standard model for separation of a JJavaScript app with production and developer components

Tags: javascript, uglifyjs, terser

I am new to JavaScript so forgive the simple question - after doing a lot of research, I am even more confused...

The app I am writing had production (display of data etc.) and developer (tools to debug, display internal state etc.) components/source files and I am looking for the best way to keep them separate so that at any point, I can "ship" the production JS file, not ship the developer JS file and things still work.

Currently, I expose functions on both side using the `window.x = x` paradigm and my production code is peppered with `if (mode !== 'prod')` type statements.

It feels very inelegant and like there must be a better way.

I looked at using `uglify` with the hope that it might strip developer code (and any calls to it) but it only seems to remove unused code.

Any pointers about where to look appreciated.

Mollu.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution like webpack, which bundles all your code, and where you can set they build mode? Are you exposing configuration settings that contain sensitive data (in which case, uglify is just not enough, load the data from a secure backend call), what's your setup and what's the ideal outcome?

Comment: I run the app in a local web server while I am developing it and edit the prod/dev JS files as I go.  Having a publish step that processed the source files, removed unwanted code etc. sounds like what I need.  There is no sensitive data - API keys etc. - in the code so simple minification would be fine vs. something more aggressive.

Comment: wrapping code in a "feature" toggle or environment flag is the normal way to do this, the more hardcore version is to create a "core" codebase with common components and have two seperate builds of the app, but thats a lot of work that needs business case to justify. what you're already doing is standard practice. JS bundles are so small there's little value in optimizing there.